# Generate close-up photo of laptop screen (with pixels)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing, screenshot, screen-printing

Given a standard screenshot, would you know how to transform it into a **close-up photo of laptop screen** effect, in which you can see the pixels.

Example:

[image] or even better, a more 3D image like [this](https://blog.verisign.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/domain-browser_625px.jpg) one.

Comment: perhaps one could make a pattern overlay to simulate a pixel grid and set the layer to "darken" or other suitable blend option. Probably "close enough" to impart a flavor without needing to simulate subpixels etc. The pattern would need to be specific to a particular screen size or the grid would look funny against the actually-rendered pixel boundaries.

Comment: It's interesting that your example doesn't show much in the way of sub-pixel effects in the white areas.  If I hold a magnifier over the white space next to it, set up to give similar size pixels, I definitely do see coloured  sub-pixels (on a bog-standard office Iiyama, looks like 95ppi)

Comment: I would zoom into Photoshop canvas and take a screen shot, then skew the perspective to imitate a photo. That would show pixels, as the OP requested. It would not of course show LCD monitor pels/artifacts, as the long procedure below imitates. But that procedure is a heck of a lot of effort for something you can quickly screenshot, or for the ultimate realism, shoot with a digital camera in 1 minute.

Comment: @user8356 I'm not sure to understand the technique you describe, can you explain it more? Would zooming in Photoshop and take a screen shot create a "grid", similar to the one we see in close-up of a LCD monitor?

Comment: I know a very good CRT shader for Blender: https://mrmotarius.itch.io/mrmocrt Not many laptops with CRTs, of course...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's an comparison between an RGB image (left) and how it looks when photographed in extreme close-up (right):

[image]

The LCD [sub-pixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-pixel) pattern is apparent and we also see how the pattern is slightly blurred and that the light of the sub-pixels bleed into each other.

Let's begin by making an LCD sub-pixel pattern. The smallest one I can imagine is the following 9×9 px pattern:

[image] [image]

Each sub-pixel is 2×7 px in respectively pure RGB red, green and blue. Vertically we have 1 px black padding between each sub-pixel and horizontally we have 2 px black padding between each pixel.

Draw the pattern in a 9×9 px document, *Select All* and use *Edit > Define Pattern* to make it into a pattern:

[image]

Let's put it to use. As example image I'll use this piece of pixel art:

[image]

<sup>© Mads Wolff</sup>

Because our pattern repeats every 9×9 px, we need to scale it up 9 times (900%) using *Nearest Neighbor* interpolation:

[image]

[image]

<sup>Click image to see full size.</sup>

We apply the pattern by adding a *Pattern* layer on top with blend mode set to *Multiply*:

[image]

[image]

<sup>Click image to see full size.</sup>

Now we need to get a little creative with filters and blend modes. There are infinite ways to do this. Here is something I just came up with. You can refine each step to your liking.

- Apply *Gaussian Blur* filter with *Radius* set to *1 px* to smoothen the pattern.
- Apply *Unsharp Mask* filter with *Amount* set to *400%*, *Radius* set to *3 px* and *Threshold* set to *0 levels* to make the sub-pixels blend together.
- Apply *Gaussian Blur* filter with *Radius* set to *0.5 px* to smoothen the pattern a bit again.
- Apply *Gaussian Blur* filter with *Radius* set to *4 px* and *Blend Mode* set to *Screen* to add some glow.
- Add a *Levels* adjustment layer to lighten the image and add some contrast.
- Add the original image on top with *Blend Mode* set to *Hue* and *Opacity* set to *50%* to add back some of the lost saturation to the image.

I would use a *Smart Object* with *Smart Filters* to make the filters non-destructive:

[image]

[image]

<sup>Click image to see full size.</sup>

This can be seen as the "raw material" for further manipulation. For example add some perspective by using *Free Transform*, apply *Lens Blur* filter, add a slight reflection, use *Camera Raw* filter to correct the image like a photo, add some *grain* in the process:

[image]

<sup>Click image to see full size.</sup>

Comment: Wonderful post @Wolff! Here is what I got with your technique for this actual webpage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwLEf.png

Comment: @Basj, Nice! A little bit moiré which perhaps could be avoided somehow tweaking the blurring. But then again, a real photograph could have that kind of moiré as well.

Comment: @Wolff if the goal is to mimic a real photo of a typical screen display, the Moire makes it. OTOH your pixel art example is (IMO) better without

Comment: @Basj that's not a photo??? wow

Comment: @htmlcoderexe A screenshot + the technique described in this answer :)

Comment: Wolff, you are a legend!!

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this from a screenshot, only from a photograph. An image file does not have pixels made up from three coloured dots, each image pixel is a distinct shade -

[image]

You need a camera with either a macro lens or a long lens, so that you can focus on a small area.

[image]

You can even get something approximate with a phone camera…

[image]

A tripod would have helped both these efforts considerably ;)

Comment: Of course, yes :) But maybe are there Photoshop tools to recreate this pixel "grid" + blur effects?

Comment: @Basj Obviously just zoom into the image with nearest neigbour shift shannels etc.

Comment: You're also going to have to model a whole bunch of teeny circles with darker borders, smaller than each 'pixel', even in pure white areas. Then you're going to have to guesstimate some appropriate perspective & add a lens blur. Quicker to get the camera out.